# Asus ASMB4 KVM - How to restart from bash command line?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ipmi, asus, bmc

I have a remote server that hasnt been access in a while and it seems the KVM web interface is not working. I can SSH in and get a prompt but I dont have any idea how to either:

-reboot the KVM only (I dont want and cant restart the machine)

or

-restart the web gui service.

Can someone out there help? I have looked over the asus documentation and there is no info on command line functions. Their help site includes info for using ipmitool and asmc4 both of which I cannot find on my machine.

I have not been able to start smash which may be of some help too because ipmitool may run under that.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1):

> help site includes info for using ipmitool and asmc4 both of which I cannot find on my machine

Why not install them? With [ipmitool(1)](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/ipmitool) installed you could reset your BMC by typing

```
$ sudo ipmitool mc reset cold
```

— it often helps me when I deal with freezed IPMI/BMC.